# How are Git websites such as GitHub and BitBucket made?

Tags: git, web-applications, github, repository, bitbucket

I was wondering how git sites are built:

What language is normally used?

Where do they store the repo's?

How do they store the repo's?

How do they allow you to connect via the CLI?

And finally, if I wanted to start a git repo storage site how would I start?

---

Any info is appreciated. As long as you answer one of my questions, I will be satisfied

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source git server called [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq). You can find all features [here](https://about.gitlab.com/features/). And build your own server check [this](https://about.gitlab.com/).